# How can I more strictly guarantee a proper typecast when referencing a template object?

Tags: java, eclipse, generics, compiler-warnings, suppress-warnings

I have a Java class that acts as a container of another generic class. It stores the objects of the generic class in a vector. For reasons too complicated to get into, mostly related to obsessive refactoring (thanks Gil), the class contains a method that does nothing but add an element to the vector. So in summary I have something like this:

```
public abstract class DataElementArray<E extends DataElement>
extends ComplexDataElement
implements DataElement, Iterable<E>
{
    private Vector<E> m_vMembers ;

    @Override
    public abstract DataElementArray<E> addChild( DataElement de ) ;
    // This method is expected to make use of the following utility method:

    @Override
    protected DataElementArray<E> addChildToVector( DataElement de )
    {
        m_vMembers.add( (E)de ) ;
        return this ;
    }

    // other stuff ...
}
```

On that line that does the typecasting from `DataElement` to `E`, Eclipse gives me the following warning:

```
Type safety: Unchecked cast from DataElement to E
```

I wouldn't think that this would be a problem, because it's already defined at the top of the class that `E` extends `DataThing`.

Short of using the `@SuppressWarnings` annotation to shut up the Eclipse hint service (which it suggested itself, strangely enough), what more can I do to alleviate this warning? Should I bother enclosing this line in a `try {} catch(ClassCastException)` block, even though I know that the source class will always be castable into the target?

Comment: Why aren't these methods taking an `E`, rather than a `DataElement`?

Comment: Because this class is one of several subclasses of `AbstractDataElement` which do _not_ use generics and the abstract superclass prototype expects `DataElement`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't and shouldn't get rid of this warning when you're casting to `E` here.  The source class, `DataElement`, may not always be cast-able to the target `E`. You can't cast to `E`, because `E` could be a subclass of `DataElement`, and a downcast here is completely inappropriate.

The easiest way to fix this is to make the parameter `de` of type `E`, but given that this method seems to override something in the superclass `ComplexDataElement`, the superclass method needs to take an `E` also.  That would mean that `ComplexDataElement` should be generic with something like `<E extends DataElement>` also.